# Azure Iotedge start docker with --net=host so that I can access my IP

Tags: spring-boot, docker, azure-iot-edge

I would like in my Java code to find my IP address. My code is inside a docker container and I always get the IP address of the docker container instead of my machine.
I run the docker like this

```
        docker run -p 8080:8080 --privileged --net=host -d 6b45f71550a3
```

This is my Java code

```
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        String hostname = InetAddress.getByName(addr.getHostName()).toString();
```

I need to modify the **deployment.template.json** so that the generated docker does take the IP Address of the machine

```
    "modules": {
      "MyModule": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "type": "docker",
        "status": "running",
        "restartPolicy": "always",
        "settings": {
          "image": "dev.azurecr.io/dev:0.0.1-arm32v7",
          "createOptions": {
            "ExposedPorts":{"8080/tcp": {}}, 
            "HostConfig": {
              "PortBindings": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                  {
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to say that you can't do that but apparently you can by using

```
"createOptions": {
  "NetworkingConfig": {
    "EndpointsConfig": {
      "host": {}
    }
  },
  "HostConfig": {
    "NetworkMode": "host"
  }
}
```

I haven't tried it. I found it here: https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-v1/issues/517. Maybe that will help.

Comment: It's now supported also by the simulator too (https://github.com/Azure/iotedgehubdev/pull/204)